# How to set gulp.dest() in same directory as pipe inputs?

Tags: gulp

I need all the found images in each of the directories to be optimized and recorded into them without setting the path to the each folder separately. I don't understand how to make that.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');

gulp.task('optimizeJpg', function () {

return gulp.src('./images/**/**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(imageminJpegtran({ progressive: true })())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify file in place (same dest) using Gulp.js and a globbing pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247642/modify-file-in-place-same-dest-using-gulp-js-and-a-globbing-pattern)

Comment: The only problem in the original code snippet is that `dest` is being called with `'./'` instead of the base, `'./images'`.  Fixing that error would make this work without changing the approach.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here are two answers.
**First:** It is longer, less flexible and needs additional modules, but it works 20% faster and gives you logs for every folder.

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

var folders =
[
    "./pictures/news/",
    "./pictures/product/original/",
    "./pictures/product/big/",
    "./pictures/product/middle/",
    "./pictures/product/xsmall/",
    ...
];

gulp.task('optimizeImgs', function () {

    var tasks = folders.map(function (element) {

        return gulp.src(element + '*')
            .pipe(sometingToDo())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(element));

    });

    return merge(tasks);

});
```

**Second solution:** It's flexible and elegant, but slower. I prefer it.

```
return gulp.src('./pictures/**/*')
    .pipe(somethingToDo())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
        return file.base;
    }));
```

Comment: can solution 2 be improved to work with unknown folder depth? I'd like to iterate trough whole folder structure?

Comment: @Rouz it already works with unknown folder depth. `foo/**/*` means all files in foo and any level of its subdirectories. Two double stars is redundant.

Comment: I've been looking for this for ages! I couldn't accept that you can't output files where they are! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just wanted to add that solution 2 works great when you're using a `tsconfig.json` file to specify input/output (for those landing here with that circumstance). Firstly, ensure you comment out (or remove) *outDir*. Second, if you're using **babel** (gulpfile.babel.js), you can make it even more elegant: `gulp.dest( file => file.base )`. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 13):

Here you go:

```
gulp.task('optimizeJpg', function () {

    return gulp.src('./images/**/**/*.jpg')
        .pipe(imageminJpegtran({ progressive: true })())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./images/'));
});
```

Gulp takes everything that's a wildcard or a globstar into its virtual file name. So all the parts you know you want to select (like `./images/`) have to be in the destination directory.

Comment: Why two double stars?

Comment: @turibe, The double stars are the **wildcards** mentioned by ddbrrt

Comment: @MarioAlbertoContreras one pair should suffice. "./images/**/*.jpg" is just as good as "./images/**/**/*.jpg"

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `base` parameter:

```
gulp.task('uglify', function () {
  return gulp.src('./dist/**/*.js', { base: "." })
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```